# Approximation involving Gamma function: $\frac{\Gamma(j+d)}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(d)}\approx(j-1)^{d-1}$

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation, gamma-function

With $d\leq 1$ and
$$
a_j=\frac{\Gamma(j+d)}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(d)}=\frac{d(d+1)\ldots(d+j-1)}{j!},\quad j=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
my professor wrote in class that
$$
\sum_{j=N}^\infty |a_j|\approx\sum_{j=N}^\infty(j-1)^{d-1}\approx\int_N^\infty x^{d-1}dx=\left.\frac{x^d}{d}\right|_N^\infty.
$$
(Context: we were mainly concerned with the boundedness of $\sum_j |a_j|$.)

How do I understand/justify the first approximation above? I tried playing with Stirling approximation but I didn't get anything. I have very little experience working with the Gamma function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it help to know that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ ?

Comment: @ Danny: I know that one :) (I edited the question to reflect that). If you know the explanation to my question, please elaborate. I would like to learn it from you. Thank you!

Comment: I may not have seen the part $d \leq 1 $ - this makes it a little more difficult, since you then can't necessarily use the factorial function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $n~(n-1)~(n-2)~\cdots~(n-k)\approx n^{k+1}$ for large *n* and fixed *k*.

Comment: @ Lucian: forgive my obtuseness, but I think in this case, my $k$ isn't fixed.

Comment: @KimJongUn: As far as I can see, your *d* doesn't vary, your *j* does, which is precisely what your teacher used in his first series approximation. Unfortunately, you chose the unhelpful expression, with both varying numerator and varying denominator.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, assuming $j,d$ are positive integers,
$$
a_j = \frac{\Gamma(j+d)}{\Gamma{j+1}\Gamma{d}} = \frac{(j+d-1)!}{j!(d-1)!} = \frac{(j+d-1)\cdots(j+1)}{(d-1)!}.
$$
Using $1+x \leq \exp x$,
you can bound
$$
\begin{align*}
a_j &\leq (j+d-1)\cdots(j+1) \\ &= (j+1)^{d-1} \left(1+\frac{d-2}{j}\right) \left(1+\frac{d-3}{j}\right) \cdots \left(1+\frac{0}{j}\right) \\ &=
(j+1)^{d-1} \exp \frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2j}.
\end{align*}
$$
If $(d-1)(d-2) \leq 2j$ then
$$
a_j \leq e (j+1)^{d-1}.
$$
More accurately, we get
$$
a_j \leq (j+1)^{d-1} \left(1 + \frac{e}{2} \frac{d^2}{j}\right),
$$
so in particular, if $d^2 \ll j$, we get a bound of the form $a_j = (j+1)^{d-1} (1 + o(1))$. A matching lower bound can be obtained using similar methods.

Comment: @ Yuval: thank you very much and +1. I edited the question slightly to change $a_j$ to $|a_j|$. I apologize, but could you please adjust to this change? Your solution will be very instructive to me.

Comment: Assuming $j+\lceil d \rceil \geq 1$, you can use $\Gamma(j+d) \leq \Gamma(j+ \lceil d \rceil)$ together with the recurrence $\Gamma(j+1) = j(j-1)\cdots(j+\lceil d\rceil) \Gamma(j+\lceil d\rceil)$ to obtain similar results.

Comment: @ Yuval: thank you. I will study your answer and will accept after I understand it fully. Meanwhile, if you want to add any details, please feel free to. Regards.